# Python - Show Results from all Pages not just the first page (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have been making a simple scraper using Beautiful Soup to get food hygiene rating of restaurants based on postcode entered by user. The code works correctly and takes results from the URL correctly.

What I need help with is how to get all the results to display, not just the results from the first page.

My code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pc = input("Please enter postcode")

url = "https://www.scoresonthedoors.org.uk/search.php?name=&address=&postcode="+pc+"&distance=1&search.x=8&search.y=6&gbt_id=0&award_score=&award_range=gt"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result"})

for item in g_data:
    print (item.find_all("a", {"class": "name"})[0].text)
try:
    print (item.find_all("span", {"class": "address"})[0].text)
except:
    pass
try:
    print (item.find_all("div", {"class": "rating-image"})[0].text)
except:
    pass
```

I have discovered by looking at the URL that the page shown is dependent on a variable in the URL string called page

```
https://www.scoresonthedoors.org.uk/search.php?award_sort=ALPHA&name=&address=BT147AL&x=0&y=0&page=2#results
```

The pagination code for the Next Page button is:

```
<a style="float: right" href="?award_sort=ALPHA&amp;name=&amp;address=BT147AL&amp;x=0&amp;y=0&amp;page=3#results" rel="next " title="Go forward one page">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-3"></i></a>
```

Is there a way I can get my code to find out how many pages of results are presented and then grab the results from each of these pages?

Would the best solution to this be to have code that alters the URL string to change "page=" each time (e.g a for loop) or is there a way to find a solution using the information in the pagination link code?

Many thanks for anyone who provides help or looks at this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually going the right way. Generating the paginated urls to scrape beforehand is a good approach.

I actually nearly wrote the whole code. What you want to look at is the `find_max_page()` function first which consists on taking the max page from the pagination string. With this number, you can then generate all the urls that you need to scrape, and scrape them one by one.

Check the code below, it's pretty much all there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RestaurantScraper(object):

    def __init__(self, pc):
        self.pc = pc        # the input postcode
        self.max_page = self.find_max_page()        # The number of page available
        self.restaurants = list()       # the final list of restaurants where the scrape data will at the end of process

    def run(self):
        for url in self.generate_pages_to_scrape():
            restaurants_from_url = self.scrape_page(url)
            self.restaurants += restaurants_from_url     # we increment the  restaurants to the global restaurants list

    def create_url(self):
        """
        Create a core url to scrape
        :return: A url without pagination (= page 1)
        """
        return "https://www.scoresonthedoors.org.uk/search.php?name=&address=&postcode=" + self.pc + \
               "&distance=1&search.x=8&search.y=6&gbt_id=0&award_score=&award_range=gt"

    def create_paginated_url(self, page_number):
        """
        Create a paginated url
        :param page_number: pagination (integer)
        :return: A url paginated
        """
        return self.create_url() + "&page={}".format(str(page_number))

    def find_max_page(self):
        """
        Function to find the number of pages for a specific search.
        :return: The number of pages (integer)
        """
        r = requests.get(self.create_url())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        pagination_soup = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "paginator"})
        pagination = pagination_soup[0]
        page_text = pagination("p")[0].text
        return int(page_text.replace('Page 1 of ', ''))

    def generate_pages_to_scrape(self):
        """
        Generate all the paginated url using the max_page attribute previously scraped.
        :return: List of urls
        """
        return [self.create_paginated_url(page_number) for page_number in range(1, self.max_page + 1)]

    def scrape_page(self, url):
        """
        This is coming from your original code snippet. This probably need a bit of work, but you get the idea.
        :param url: Url to scrape and get data from.
        :return:
        """
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "search-result"})

        restaurants = list()
        for item in g_data:
            name = item.find_all("a", {"class": "name"})[0].text
            restaurants.append(name)
            try:
                print item.find_all("span", {"class": "address"})[0].text
            except:
                pass
            try:
                print item.find_all("div", {"class": "rating-image"})[0].text
            except:
                pass
        return restaurants


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pc = input('Give your post code')
    scraper = RestaurantScraper(pc)
    scraper.run()
    print "{} restaurants scraped".format(str(len(scraper.restaurants)))
```

Comment: The scrape_page function is your original code. It could use some work. Just make sure this function is well built. Everything else is pretty much ready. Any questions on this code, let me know.